# Replace \\ with \ in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, escaping, verbatim-string

I have a long string (a path) with double backslashes, and I want to replace it with single backslashes:

```
string a = "a\\b\\c\\d";
string b = a.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

This code does nothing...

`b` remains `"a\\b\\c\\d"`

I also tried different combinations of backslashes instead of using `@`, but no luck.

Comment: You should use Path.Combine for file paths anyway.. also, can I ask why?

Comment: It's a string... just represents a path

Comment: @Corak, I don't create a, I get it from somewhere else.. it just looks like a\\b\\c\\d

Comment: A downvote? seriously?

Comment: your string `a` has single backslashes already.

Comment: It doesn't. try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Exactly. It *looks* like it has two backslashes. Try `Console.WriteLine("a\\b")` and the second backslash magically disappeares.

Comment: The variable containing this string has two, therefore it crushes later on

Comment: ["By default the debugger will display backslash characters as double backslashes since it's using the backslash as a control character."](http://graperblog.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/visual-studio-2005-debugger-irritation.html) - Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: Okay, if `var a = @"a\\b";` (note the `@`), then `var b = a.Replace(@"\\", @"\");` should already get rid of the second backslash. Be sure the strings are what you think they are.

Comment: Six downvotes? That's pushing it a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, you can't have a string like `"a\b\c\d"`, because the `\` has a special meaning: it creates a [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) together with a following letter (or combination of digits).

`\b` represents actually a backspace, and `\c` and `\d` are invalid escape sequences (the compiler will complain about an "Unrecognized escape sequence").

So how do you create a string with a simple `\`? You have to use a backslash to espace the backslash:`\\` (it's the espace sequence that represents a single backslash).

That means that the string `"a\\b\\c\\d"` actually represents `a\b\c\d` (it doesn't represent `a\\b\\c\\d`, so no double backslashes). You'll see it yourself if you try to print this string.

C# also has a feature called [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) (strings that start with `@`), which allows you to write `@"a\b\c\d"` instead of `"a\\b\\c\\d"`.

Answer (score 8):

Because you declared `a` without using `@`, the string `a` does not contain any double-slashes in your example. In fact, in your example, `a == "a\b\c\d"`, so `Replace` does not find anything to replace. Try:

```
string a = @"a\\b\\c\\d";
string b = a.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Comment: I didn't declare a. I showed it here as an example. I get it like that from somewhere else

Comment: So your example is wrong and misleading then, thus we can't answer your question. Are you sure your string "*from somewhere else*" does actually contain double-slashes?

Comment: @user990635: Still: Your Replace statement is correct. It *does* remove double backslashes if there are any. Try to output `b` with `Console.WriteLine` to see for yourself.

Comment: @user990635 - please be careful on what your string variable really containes. And be aware that `"a\\b"` is *NOT* the same as `@"a\\b"`. In fact, as I already mentioned, `"a\\b"` is *the same* as `@"a\b"`.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong.  `"\\"` return `\` (know as escaping)

```
string a = "a\\b\\c\\d";
System.Console.WriteLine(a);  // prints a\b\c\d
string b = a.Replace(@"\\", @"\");  
System.Console.WriteLine(b);  // prints a\b\c\d
```

You don't even need `string b = a.Replace(@"\\", @"\");`

Answer (score 0):

this works

You don't even need string b = a.Replace(@"\", @"\");

but like if we generate a dos command through c# code... eg:- to delete a file
this wil help

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a code in a UWP application.

```
foreach (var item in Attendances)
{
   string a = item.ImagePath;
   string b = a.Replace(@"\\", "/");
   string c = a.Replace("\\", "/");

   Console.WriteLine(b);
   Console.WriteLine(a);
   item.ImagePath = c;
}
```

and the ones without the @ symbol is the one that actually worked. this is C# 8 and C# 9