# Replace string "Prab\A\kar" to "Prab\kar"

Tags: c#, string, replace

I want to replace the string Prab\A\kar to Prab\kar
I have tried like this

```
string temp = @"prab\A\kar";
temp = temp.Replace(@"\A\", @"\");
```

and i got as "prab\\kar". As i mentioned in the title I want it as "Prab\kar"

Comment: And what else did you expect?

Comment: Read this, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918071/replace-with-in-c-sharp

Comment: My bad, it works like charm when i see it in console ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = temp.Replace(@"\A\", @"\");
```

Comment: That is what I have tried and got with two \\ instead of \ in string

Comment: @rk_sweetrascal: that's just the debugger window. Click on the loup and you'll see that the result is correct.

Comment: Debugger view gets them every time!